# Storybook/react loads components in some strange way (it looks like async)

Tags: reactjs, storybook

In my code I have next:

```
import { TammIcon } from 'src/components/atoms';
// ....
      <Row>
        <Col xs={16}>
          <Row type="flex" justify="end">
            <Col xs={12}>
              <TammIcon
                type={icon}
                disabled={faded}
                className="uil-dash-card__icon"
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
        {!!completed && (
          <Col xs={8}>
            <Row type="flex" justify="end">
              <Col>
                <TammIcon
                  type="ok"
                  active
                  className="uil-dash-card__completed"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
        )}
      </Row>
```

and second usage of TammIcon gives me

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at invariant (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:11638:15)
    at getFiberTagFromObjectType (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:57065:9)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:57025:20)
    at reconcileSingleElement (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:59893:23)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:59949:35)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:60320:28)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:60311:3)
```

After debugging I discovered that `TammIcon` component doesn't imported correctly and make workaround with

```

```
import { TammIcon as TI } from 'src/components/atoms';


console.log('TI', TI); // undefined
const TammIcon = props => {
  console.log('TI', TI); // component
  return <TI {...props} />;
};
```

```

But it looks ugly and totally strange. Is there any way to explain such behaviour?

P.S. Another workaround (less code, but still strange) is to use IIF instead of static value (looks something wrong with cache/calculation time)

```
            <TammIcon
              // type='ok'
              type={(() => 'ok')()}
              active
              className="uil-dash-card__completed"
            />
```

[image]